# Converting PHP/mySQL web-app into offline PC app

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, wamp, chromium-embedded

I want to port a web-app to PC, making it full-screen and offline, and wrapped in an installer.

As browser component I want to use Awesomium (http://awesomium.com/), since the web-app optimized for Safari (Webkit). But what about server (WAMP)?

It should be free to use for redistribution or be reasonably priced. I'd prefer open-source (not binaries) to avoid just copying files and folders "as is" (binary WAMPs usually behave this way). A typical user shouldn't be able to look at Program Files and see all the PHP sources. The ideal solution supports encrypting both PHP and mySQL tables (I know about obfuscating).

Is there something ready?

Regards,

**UPDATE**

I'm now using CEF — Chromium Embedded Framework, which is a way to build your own browser in a couple of days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you can use MySQL. You can at least use SQLite using the Titanium Platform.

It makes desktop applications for you, using PHP/Python or Ruby.

Take a look here: http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/

It's free!

API reference guide: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest

Comment: I just downloaded it, after stubmling across this post, and I think I'm in love with that program ;) If I could up your post more, I would xD

Comment: On contrary, I even has not downloaded, after reading http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/get_started It looks too complex to be useful. I was looking for a portable, embeddable WAMP, that lets me encrypt my sources, not for a solution that gives me a unique AppId (why the hell I need AppId?). I also do not need tray icons etc, since I have my own web browser. Also, I want PURE web-app, that can run in both browser and offline desktop. API seems to be spoiling this pureness.